# How to display hover message in left bar in vscode active text editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing vscode extension and I want to achieve the same effect like 'Breakpoint' msg after mouse hovering:
[breakpoint hover msg in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc0LN.jpg)

I tried few things and nothing gave me correct result. Now I have:

```
vscode.commands.registerTextEditorCommand('startextension', () => {
   let decorationsOptions : vscode.DecorationOptions[] =[];
   decorationsOptions.push({hoverMessage: 'Works', range: new vscode.Range(3, 0, 3, 0)});
   vscode.window.activeTextEditor.setDecorations(vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({}), decorationsOptions);
});
```

Unfortunately after launching extension and hovering over selected line I get nothing.
This solution works for example for displaying custom icon, but not for hovering.

Do I have to register special hover provider to see my "Works" msg?

Comment: Just a guess: is the range too small? Does it require a minimum size?

Comment: No. Range is to set start end end position. In example it is restricted to 3 line (start position: 3, end position: 3). Unfortunately it isn't connected with my issue.